# Flex Air program crash when press TAB key

Tags: apache-flex, air

this problem block me for two days.  When i launch my Flex Air program,  then if I press TAB key, it will crash and show

ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/getChildIndex()
    at mx.core::Container/getChildIndex()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\mx\src\mx\core\Container.as:2835]
    at mx.containers::Panel/getChildIndex()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\mx\src\mx\containers\Panel.as:1179]
    at fl.managers::FocusManager/getChildIndex()
    at fl.managers::FocusManager/sortByDepth()
    at Array$/_sort()
    at Array/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::sort()
    at fl.managers::FocusManager/sortFocusableObjects()
    at fl.managers::FocusManager/keyDownHandler()

how to fix? thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your tab press doesn't try to set a focus on some DisplayObject which is not actually added as a child of the parent container? Because the error message basically says:"I can't focus on this DisplayObject because it is not a child of the container " ...

Comment: when the air program is booted up, tab it ,it will crash. After i add "this.tabChildren = false;" It will not tab crash again, i don't know why. But in the popupwindow, the tab still lead to crash. And the popupwindow parent is the air program.